# how do I get rid of this google searchbar?

Tags: nexus-7, user-interface, google-search

I have a Google searchbar in a tablet I have borrowed
[image]
For me it's in a very inconvenient location and I keep on pressing it accidentally.
It looks like I can't click and drag on it to move it to another location either.
How do I hide this toolbar? I need to be able to get it back as well, since the tablet isn't mine, but I want to hide or disable this search bar while I use it (or at least move it to another location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar is a built-in part of the default launcher and can't be moved or disabled. The least invasive way to get rid of it is to install a new launcher of your choice and use that instead of the default one. The old launcher is still installed, and will come back when you uninstall the new one, so the question is just whether you ought to install software on this device you've borrowed.

Comment: I have no idea how to install a launcher and I don't want to do anything that may trash the system. So am I stuck with it? Is there any way I can disable it? I don't mind it being there, I just don't want it to be clicked accidentally

Comment: if it can be moved to another location on the screen that would be fine as well

Comment: Is it possible to do something like pass a command line parameter for this launcher to disable this toolbar then restart the launcher, using adb?

Comment: @user17915 Installing a launcher won't trash the system: it's just like installing any other app.

Comment: Go to Google Play and install, say, Nova Launcher. Then just disable the search bar.  Simple as that.

Comment: A launcer like Nova has an option called 'Persistant Search Bar' that can be disabled if you want it gone. There MAY be a setting in display on your device, try having a look around for that in the settings. A launcher is just an app from the Play Store and Apex and Nova (as exapmples) are excellent! They're simple, light, easy to customise and 100% trustworthy. You won't trash anything with it and you can always uninstall it if you don't like it. They are free apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deactivate that, not to my knowledge anyway. You can install something like Smart Launcher, Next Launcher or Go Launcher which have extreme flexibility in what you can do. It's just like installing any other app, and the next time you hit your "Home" button you select that launcher "Just Once" to test it out.

Answer (score -1):

Press it, hold your finger over it, then a red trash can will appear. Drag it to the trash can.

Press & hold to start the drag & drop.

Press & hold on an empty space to bring up a menu to add widgets. Then select the search widget to bring it back.

Comment: It's not a widget, so that won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Google Search can be deactivated in the system settings, in the apps. It then appears at the bottom of the apps in the system settings, where it can be activated. It cannot be deinstalled. (If it were able to be deinstalled, you can back it up using Astro File Explorer, and using any file exporer re-install it).