# How to remove Google box from home screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-tab

I believe this app is called S Voice. How can I remove it completely?

[image]

Sometimes it pops up when I unlock the tablet without me trying to open it. And even if it didn't I would want to remove it anyway because I don't need the functionality it provides (I don't even know what it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app (formerly known as **Google Search**).

> Google app for Android: The fastest, easiest way to find what you need on the web and on your device.
>
> - Quickly search the web and your phone or tablet
> - Use your voice to search and more
> - Get personalised results based on your location
>
> [image]

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; image modified but originally taken from Play Store)</sub>

As for how to disable it, see [How to disable Google Search?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63090/96277) -- usually, it is **Settings → Apps → All apps→ Google (or Google Search) → Disable**.

While I was able to disable this app in my CyanogenOS 12, there is an answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52488/96277) which contradicts with my statement. Perhaps, it is still valid for some specific scenarios. I recommend a look at it.

To remove it, see [Rooted Phone but still can't uninstall Apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8290/96277).

Also consider https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86475/nexus-5-stuck-in-boot-loop-after-disabling-google-search.

Comment: [Remove bloatware on Galaxy S2 - what are my options?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30155)

Comment: Should I edit my question to say Google App instead of S Voice?

Comment: Good point. If you edit the question and write clearly that it is Google app and you want it removed, then both the answers will have to be edited as well. In order to avoid, write the title something like: "how to remove the search box from my home screen in" the device you have? As for body, leave it untouched since you were not really sure what the box was, and this way the other answer would remain valid without an edit.

Comment: So, did you disable it or remove it?

Comment: It got disabled, meaning nothing happens when I tap on it now and it no longer appears sometimes when I unlock the device. When I tried to disable it I got a popup asking if I want to replace it with the "factory version" of the app, and I had to choose to do that in order to proceed. So basically the box is still there but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user11177 If the box is still a nuisance, then you may try a different launcher app (like Nova Launcher). It would replace the home screen, and the box would be gone for good.  // Otherwise, rooting and then removing that app is always the best thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well that should be the Google app. 
You can try to deactivate it if you go into settings - applications - Google - deactivate / deinstall updates.

S-Voice is the samsung voice search. It gets triggered by a double home-button click on some samsung devices. If you open up S-Voice and go into the settings, you can deactivate the trigger. 
You may even be able to deactivate it like the google application.

I hope this helps you.